# Search string to find Filename

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a way in C# to search a string for the file and it's extension.  So for example if I have a string "//houtestserver/common/file1.pdf" how can I set another string to file1.pdf?

Thanks everyone in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.IO.Path.GetFileName("//houtestserver/common/file1.pdf");` will return "file1.pdf".  Is that enough for your needs?

Answer (score 1):

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
```